# How to send email, when users roles change - User Manager customization

Tags: user-management, role-management, membership-provider

I've been tasked with an interesting challenge. The client wants a user to be sent an email informing them when they have been assigned to a specific role by an Admin.

What will be the best way to go about this?

Is it possible to do this via Workflows? Or will other methods be required?

Answer (score 12):

One option is to hook into Sitecore's `user:updated` event (and optionally `user:updated:remote`). This event is raised when a user has been updated, the remote event handler is raised when a user was updated on a remote Sitecore instance.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments by @SzymonKuzniak, you can also hook into the `roles:usersAdded[:remote]` event to specifically handle added roles. Likewise, there is also the `roles:rolesRemoved[:remote]` event.

Create a new configuration file and put it in App_Config\Include:

```xml
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="user:updated">
        <handler type="Custom.UserUpdatedEventHandler, Custom" method="OnUserUpdated"/>
      </event>
      <event name="user:updated:remote">
        <handler type="Custom.UserUpdatedEventHandler, Custom" method="OnUserUpdatedRemote"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Create a class `UserUpdatedEventHandler` in the `Custom` namespace:

```cs
public class UserUpdatedEventHandler
{
    public void OnUserUpdated(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        var sitecoreArgs = (SitecoreEventArgs)args;
        var membershipUser = (MembershipUser)sitecoreArgs.Parameters[0];

        // Check user and roles

        // Send e-mail
    }

    public void OnUserUpdatedRemote(object o, EventArgs args)
    {
        var sitecoreArgs = (SitecoreEventArgs)args;
        var userRemoteEventArgs = (UserUpdatedRemoteEventArgs)sitecoreArgs.Parameters[0];
        var userName = userRemoteEventArgs.UserName;

        // Check user and roles

        // Send e-mail
    }
}
```

Comment: There's also roles:usersAdded which handles specifically the case of users being added to role.

Comment: Good suggestion. After trying this I keep getting the following error at this point: var membershipUser = (MembershipUser)sitecoreArgs.Parameters[0];                           "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.Web.Security.MembershipUser'.

Comment: @user337 That is because the `roles:usersAdded` event has other arguments than the `user:updated` event. Probably - haven't tested this myself - the argument is an array of usernames that were added to the role. You need to inspect which parameters the `sitecoreArgs` has and act accordingly. I guess there must be a rolename somewhere too.

Comment: @user337 has this answered your question? If so please mark it as answered

Comment: @user1924455 - Please mark this as answered