# Which event to extend when a role is added to user

Tags: user-management, role-management, account

I would like to log when a role is added or removed for a user.
But none of these methods are being triggered on such use cases.

**patch.config:**

```
<sitecore>
  <events>
    <event name="roles:usersAdded">
        <handler type="MyCode.AccountEventHandler, MyCode" method="OnRoleAddedForUser"/>
    </event>
    <event name="roles:usersRemoved">
        <handler type="MyCode.AccountEventHandler, MyCode" method="OnRoleRemovedForUser"/>
    </event>
    <event name="user:runtimerolesupdated">
      <handler type="MyCode.AccountEventHandler, MyCode" method="OnUserRuntimeRolesUpdated"/>
    </event>
    <event name="user:updated">
      <handler type="MyCode.AccountEventHandler, MyCode" method="OnUserUpdated"/>
    </event>
  </events>
</sitecore>
```

**AccountEventHandler.cs**

```
protected void OnRoleAddedForUser(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("Role added for user");
        }

        protected void OnRoleRemovedForUser(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("Role removed for user");
        }
        
        protected void OnUserRuntimeRolesUpdated(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("Role updated for user");
        }

        protected void OnUserUpdated(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("user updated");
        }
```

I have extended other events like `user:created` & `user:deleted`. They work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the code for the **Edit User** Dialogue from the **User Manager**, here is the location of the file in the Sitecore webroot.

```
inetpub\wwwroot\<your application root>\sitecore\shell\Applications\Security\EditUser\EditUser.xaml.xml
```

This file refers to the DLL i.e. `Sitecore.Client` and the event is written in this class `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Security.EditUser.EditUserPage`. And here is the code snippet to add Edit User or Role.

```
protected override void OK_Click()
{
  if (!this.Validate() || !this.ValidateTicket())
    return;
  User user = EditUserPage.GetUser();
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) user, typeof (User), "User not found");
  UserProfile profile = user.Profile;
  Assert.IsNotNull((object) profile, typeof (UserProfile));
  try
  {
    IEnumerable<Role> roles = this.Roles.Items.Cast<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>().Where<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem>((Func<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem, bool>) (item => System.Web.Security.Roles.RoleExists(item.Value))).Select<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem, Role>((Func<System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem, Role>) (item => Role.FromName(item.Value)));
    HttpContext current = HttpContext.Current;
    Assert.IsNotNull((object) current, typeof (HttpContext));
    string controlValue = string.Empty;
    foreach (string key in current.Request.Form.Keys)
    {
      if (key != null && key.EndsWith("StartUrlSelector", StringComparison.InvariantCulture))
      {
        controlValue = current.Request.Form[key];
        break;
      }
    }
    if (controlValue == "Default")
      controlValue = string.Empty;
    if (controlValue == "Custom")
      controlValue = this.StartUrl.Text;
    user.Roles.Replace(roles);
    ....
    ....
}
```

So you can override this class and replace it in the XML file to use your logic.

You can also try this with an Update event like this.

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events>
      <event name="user:updated">
        <handler type="Custom.UserUpdatedEventHandler, Custom" method="OnUserUpdated"/>
      </event>
      <event name="user:updated:remote">
        <handler type="Custom.UserUpdatedEventHandler, Custom" method="OnUserUpdatedRemote"/>
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

See this thread for more details.

[How to send email, when users roles change - User Manager customization](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/36/how-to-send-email-when-users-roles-change-user-manager-customization)

I hope this will help.

Comment: I have extended other events like `user:created` & `user:deleted`. Those are triggered fine.

Comment: So on `OnUserUpdated` event are you not able to write code for role?

Comment: `OnUserUpdated` is not being triggered when I add/remove a role.

Comment: I added some more information to my answer. Please check the link I sent in answer.